# Declaration Error in Nested Struct

Tags: solidity, remix

I am writing the contract below to store json in a nested struct in remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract Analytics {
  address lastAddress;
  uint timeStamp;
  string label;
  uint count;
  string id;
  string typeofEntry; // lack of better terminology 
  string channel;
  string createdAt;
//   uint totalAmount; 
  struct Field {
    string typeOfFunding; // type is a reserved word in solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords
    uint amount;
    string cohort;
    string promotion;
  }
  struct Entry {
    string id;
    string typeofEntry; // lack of better terminology 
    string channel;
    Field funding;
    string createdAt;
    uint totalAmount; 
  }
  mapping(uint => Entry) public entries;
function updateEntry (string memory _id,
                      string memory _typeOfEntry,
                      string memory _channel,
                      string memory _typeofFunding,
                      uint  _amount,
                      string memory _cohort,
                      string memory _promotion,
                      string memory _createdAt,
                      uint  _totalAmount) public returns 
                      (bool sucess)
    {
      entries[id] = id; 
      entries[typeofEntry]= _typeOfEntry;
      entries[channel]= _channel;
      entries[funding].typeOfFunding = _typeofFunding;
      entries[funding].amount = _amount;
      entries[funding].cohort = _cohort;
      entries[funding].promotion = _promotion;
      entries[createdAt] = _createdAt;
      entries[totalAmount]= _totalAmount;
      return true;
    }
}
```

I am however getting a

> Declaration Error: Undeclared Identifier

In the lines below:

```
  entries[funding].typeOfFunding = _typeofFunding;
      entries[funding].amount = _amount;
      entries[funding].cohort = _cohort;
      entries[funding].promotion = _promotion;
```

Not sure what the issue is and will appreciate pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can insert nested structs:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract Analytics {
    address lastAddress;
    uint timeStamp;
    string label;
    uint count;
    string id;
    string typeofEntry; // lack of better terminology 
    string channel;
    string createdAt;
    //   uint totalAmount; 
    struct Field {
        string typeOfFunding; // type is a reserved word in solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords
        uint amount;
        string cohort;
        string promotion;
    }
    struct Entry {
        string id;
        string typeofEntry; // lack of better terminology 
        string channel;
        string createdAt;
        uint totalAmount; 
        Field funding;
    }
    mapping(uint => Entry) entries;

    function updateEntry (
                    uint _index,
                    string memory _id,
                    string memory _typeOfEntry,
                    string memory _channel,
                    string memory _typeofFunding,
                    uint  _amount,
                    string memory _cohort,
                    string memory _promotion,
                    string memory _createdAt,
                    uint  _totalAmount) public returns 
                    (bool sucess)
    {
        entries[_index] = Entry(_id, _typeOfEntry, _channel, _createdAt, _totalAmount, Field(_typeofFunding, _amount, _cohort, _promotion));
        return true;
    }
}
```

However I saw that you defined `entries` as mapping with `uint` type for key, but you are not setting the key in your example. In my example I added one more parameter to the function called `_index` which will be the mapping key for struct that is going to be inserted. Later you can easy access that struct by the key, you just have to add on getter method which returns struct data by the mapping key. If you don't want to setup key you can use array of structs:

```
Entry[] entries;

function updateEntry (string memory _id,
                  string memory _typeOfEntry,
                  string memory _channel,
                  string memory _typeofFunding,
                  uint  _amount,
                  string memory _cohort,
                  string memory _promotion,
                  string memory _createdAt,
                  uint  _totalAmount) public returns 
                  (bool sucess)
{
    entries.push(Entry(_id, _typeOfEntry, _channel, _createdAt, _totalAmount, Field(_typeofFunding, _amount, _cohort, _promotion)));
    return true;
}
```